# WPF ObservableCollection hasn't updated when DataContext has changed

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, observablecollection

I have `Data = new ObservableCollection<DATA>(dataContext.DATA);`

`dataContext` is my Entities. `DATA` is SQL Server table.

Now I run Import method, which fills `DATA` table on SQL Server:

```
    public static void Import(DataTable table)
    {
        var dataContext = DataContext.Instance.Entities;

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            .......

            var dataRow = new DATA
            {
               .........
            };

            dataContext.AddToDATA(dataRow);
        }
        dataContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But my ObservableCollection `Data` is still empty. How do I update it?

Comment: If you're using the newer `DbContext` API, you can use the [Local property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) on the `DbSet`, which will [automatically stay in sync with the context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/02/01/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-7-local-data.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ObservableCollection<T> Constructor (IEnumerable<T>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx):

> Initializes a new instance of the ObservableCollection class that
>   contains elements copied from the specified collection.

The keyword here is that it **copies** the element from the collection. After that it does not retain any synchronization with the enumeration that you passed in. Your code is updating the `dataContext` object, not your `Data` object (The ObservableCollection). You will either have to build out your own synchronized version of ObservableCollection or create methods to keep them in sync.

If you aren't concerned with keeping the `dataContext` object synchronized and only wanted to use it in the one-time load, then you have to have all the appropriate objects in that enumeration before using it in the constructor of your ObservableCollection.

My guess is you do something similar to the following:

```
Data = new ObservableCollection<DATA>(dataContext.DATA)

// Afterwards...
Import(foobar);
```

It should be:

```
Import(foobar);

// Afterwards...
Data = new ObservableCollection<DATA>(dataContext.DATA)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it's pretty useful. The structure of the app is a little mode complicated. `Data` collections belongs to `DocumentViewModel`, but I run `Import(foobar)` from `DashboardViewModel`: user press Import button -> DashboardViewModel's RelayCommand -> Import(foobar). Actually, I don't have an access to `Data` collection from `DashboardViewModel`. What would you suggest in my case? `DocumentViewModel` also has a descendants

Comment: I'm thinking of using `Messenger` to broadcast a message to all of `DocumentViewModel`'s descendants to update their `Data` collections, but I'm not sure this solution will not affect to performance...

Answer (score 1):

You need to reget the data from the datacontext and add it to the observable collection at that point.

```
public static void Import(DataTable table)
{
    var dataContext = DataContext.Instance.Entities;

    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        .......

        var dataRow = new DATA
        {
           .........
        };

        dataContext.AddToDATA(dataRow);
    }
    dataContext.SaveChanges();

    var data = datContext.whateverretreval();

    Data = data;
}
```